# Как вызвать метод в цикле и записать return в list?

Tags: java, mysql, юнит-тесты

Метод insert вставляет записи в БД и возвращает id каждой записи. Я хочу записать в список все возвращаемые id, как это сделать?

```
for (TestTable testTable : testTables) {
        testDB.insert(testTable);
    }
```

Comment: 1) создать список 2) записывать в него каждую итерацию цикла

Comment: Как это реализовать, можешь пример показать? Метод insert возвращает int, когда я создаю List<Integer> и пытаюсь туда записывать итерации, мне выдает java.util.List<E> cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: так добавь свой код в вопрос, тебе укажут где там проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (TestTable testTable : testTables) {
     int id = testDB.insert(testTable);
     idList.add(id); 
}
```

должно быть что-то типа такого.
перед циклом создаешь список типа `Integer` и записываешь в него id созданной записи, но это при условии, что у тебя метод `insert` возвращает `int`/`Integer`

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
insertedListId = testTables.stream().map(testDB::insert).toList();
```